# "Linear algebra done right" Examples 1.37, 1.38 - Verify result for sum of subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am self studying some math subjects to help me with my material science studies, as I enjoy mathematical rigor more than using ready made equations/tools. I mention this to note that unfortunately right now, my math background is very thin besides some calculus, integrals etc. I was reading "Linear algebra done right" by Axler and I am a bit confused on these two specific examples for the sums of subsets.

> ### Example 1.37
>
> Suppose $U$ is the set of all elements of $F^3$ whose second and third coordinates equal $0$, and $W$ is the set of all elements of $F^3$ whose first and third coordinates equal $0$:
>
> $$U = \{(x,0,0) \in F^3 : x \in F\}$$ and $$W = \{(0,y,0) \in F^3 : y \in F\}$$
>
> Then
> $$U + W = \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in F\}$$
> as you should verify.

> ### Example 1.38
>
> Suppose that $U = \{(x,x,y,y) \in F^4 : x,y \in F\}$ and $W = \{(x,x,x,y) \in F^4 : x,y \in F\}$. Then
> $$U + W = \{(x,x,y,z) \in F^4: x,y,z \in F\}$$
> as you should verify.

I understand the logic in the second example, that the variable names are local and can just be replaced with a,b,c to avoid confusion. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397605/sum-of-vector-subspaces) question was about that and the answers made it clear. But I have trouble understanding what the actual question is, what am I supposed to prove/verify? I posted the first example too, because it is very simple and I would like to understand that specific case too.

In a more general problem, suppose I have two sets $U$ and $W$ and I want to find their sum, what is the formal procedure I have to follow?  Can I just add their elements and be done with it or do I have to prove the set equality after (one is the subset of the other and vice versa)? I guess that seems trivial for the two examples I posted because of the closed under addition property of the field $F$ but I would think that more complex problems would not be as trivial.

What I tried in example 1.37:

The set to verify as the result of addition is
$$S = \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in F\}$$

and

$u = (x,0,0) \in U$, $w = (0,y,0) \in W$, $u + w = (x+0,0+y,0+0)=(x,y,0)$, therefore $u+w \in S$ ($x,y \in F$).

So, we proved that $U+W \subseteq S$, but how do we prove that $S \subseteq U + W$? I have no idea how to start. In the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397605/sum-of-vector-subspaces) question for example 1.38, he "fixes" an element $s$ of $S$ as the result we were given, $(x,x,y,z)$, and then chooses $u$ and $w$ so that they fit. Is intuitively setting elements values what you are supposed to do in all similar problems or is there a more formal methodology? And do I have to do this for every sum of sets/subsets I want to find?

I understand this is a lot to unpack, but just some nudge to a general direction would help me a lot. I would just comment on the answer but I don't have the required reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(x,y,0)\in S$, then$$(x,y,0)=\overbrace{(x,0,0)}^{\phantom U\in U}+\overbrace{(0,y,0)}^{\phantom V\in V}.$$

Concerning the other problem, since the first coordinate of every element of $U$ is equal to the second one and since the same thing occurs with $V$, it is clear that, if$$T=\{(x,x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in F\},$$then $U+V\subset T$. Now, take $(x,x,y,z)\in T$ and consider the equation $$(x,x,y,z)=(a,a,b,b)+(c,c,c,d),$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=a+c\\y=b+c\\z=b+d.\end{array}\right.$$This system has solutions; for instance, you can take $a=0$, $b=-x+y$, $c=x$, and $d=x-y+z$. This proves that every element of $T$ can be written as an element of $U$ plus an element of $V$. Therefore, $T\subset U+V$.

Comment: I think I understand, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.